# Server Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost was unable to start within 45 seconds

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I have 2 projects in eclipse. One of them runs fine and when added to Tomcat server, server can restart without any problems. However, the other project gets error when added

> Server Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost was unable to start within 45 seconds. If the
>   server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor.

I don't believe it's a timeout issue as I've changed time to no avail. Is there other settings/places I should be looking for errors?

This is console output for project that successfully starts vs one that doesn't

```
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
24-Jun-2011 15:17:38 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 472 ms
24-Jun-2011 15:17:38 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
24-Jun-2011 15:17:38 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.18
24-Jun-2011 15:17:39 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
24-Jun-2011 15:17:39 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
24-Jun-2011 15:17:39 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
24-Jun-2011 15:17:39 org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
24-Jun-2011 15:17:39 org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/47  config=null
24-Jun-2011 15:17:39 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1332 ms
```

One that fails:

```
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
24-Jun-2011 15:18:34 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 425 ms
24-Jun-2011 15:18:34 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
24-Jun-2011 15:18:34 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.18
```

Has anyone any idea on what could be stopping this from running?

Answer (score 20):

Where did you change the time for the timeout?

In eclipse:

- open your *servers* view
- doubleclick on the server
- check *Timeouts* (add a big number for *Start*)

Comment: Yeah I've changed it there (server always started in less than 45 seconds when I had everything set up correct before). Other project starts within couple of seconds so I don't think my server problem lies within Timeout

Answer (score 1):

May I know when you get this problem? If you get this while debugging, it means that it is waiting for your key press (either F5 or F6) to move to the next execution manually step by step. So you need not change the server's "timeout" property. Hope you get a little idea from this...

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message too. Sometimes it is just a library or a source folder which is out-of-synch. Please be sure that you clean your working directories, clean your projects and republish them. Sometimes it helps if you start the server first, then add the project and restart it. I was able to get this error message after that:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused. If this is the case, here you can find some suggestions to solve this problem: [java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876266/java-net-connectexception-connection-refused). Hope that it helps.
Addition: A very useful method to find out from where exactly the error comes. http://www.vogella.com/blog/2010/02/16/tomcat-unable-to-start/ .

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it occurred after I put "tcnaive-1.dll" in jre/bin.

Because I tried to remove the warning message when running the other one(tomcat6.0).

So, I deleted tcnative-1.dll for tomcat5.5-going-well even if keep warning message on tomcat6.0.