# Server Client Exception

Tags: java

I have a problem in running server-client program. When i run my server program , it keeps on running and never ends up. On other side, when i run my client program it throws an exception as shown below (my firewall is off).

The replies will be more than appreciated. Thanks

```
//Client Code
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class DailyAdviceClient
{
    public void go()
    {
        try {
            Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 4242);
            InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader z = new BufferedReader(read);
            String advice = z.readLine();
            System.out.println("today you should" + advice);
            z.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DailyAdviceClient x = new DailyAdviceClient();
        x.go();
    }
}        

 //Server Code

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class DailyAdvisor
{
    String[] advicelist = { "take your time", "be patient",
            "don't be diplomatic", " life is really short", "try to fix things" };
    public void go()
    {
        try
        {
            ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(4242);
            while (true)
            {
                Socket m = s.accept();
                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(m.getOutputStream());
                String advice = getAdvice();
                writer.println(advice);
                writer.close();
                writer.flush();
                System.out.println(advice);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private String getAdvice()
    {
        int random = (int) (Math.random() * advicelist.length);
        return advicelist[random];
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        DailyAdvisor x = new DailyAdvisor();
        x.go();
    }
}
```

[image: Exception thrown by Client]

Comment: do you really need a full line break before each line?

Comment: `while(true)` creates an never ending loop on `server` side. You are not telling, when to `break` out of `while` loop.

Comment: Can you confirm your server is listening on the port before you run the client? (look into `netstat`)

Comment: The code works perfectly for me, are you sure that you start the server before you run the client?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876266/java-net-connectexception-connection-refused: This exception usually occurs when there is no service listening on the port you are trying to connect to.

Comment: yes i am sure. i run server before the client

Comment: so how can i make sure that port is free?

Comment: @user2985842 Are you on Windows? `netstat -ano | find /i "4242"` -- If a line showing "LISTENING" appears it should be running.

Comment: no netstat -ano | find /i "4242" ... it just execute and nothing comes out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Server never ends up because you used a `while(true)` loop. It is necessary for your server to keep listening to new client connections through the `accept()` method.

About the exception, your code runs fine both locally and using a remote machine. Thus a network configuration error could be the cause and you must check if both server/client could see each other using the `ping` command. If this is the case, then check if the server is listening to the client using `netstat`.