# java.net.ConnectException in App connecting to webservice

Tags: android, web-services

My webservice Complete Run With iis server in browser with following url
"localhost:81/AIMS/Service.asmx"

and i'm using foolowing url in android application
private static final String URL="http://127.0.0.1:81/AIMS/Service.asmx";

but it's not working ...
java.net.ConnectException 127.0.0.1:81 Connection refused.

Comment: Are you using emulator?

Comment: Did you set Internet permission in Manifest?

Comment: yes...i'm using emulator and added permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Emulator then `http://10.0.2.2:8080/` is the address you should use.`127.0.0.1` or `localhost` will be emulator's loopback address.

Comment: here webservice run on 127.0.0.1:81 on browser ....
WHat should url i have to write in android??

Answer (score 0):

See this link

[java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876266/java-net-connectexception-connection-refused)

This exception usually occurs when there is no service listening on the port you are trying to connect to.

It may be a firewall issue.