# Connection refused error when executing test case for Jayway-Rest assured

Tags: java, junit, rest-assured

I am writing test case using jayway. I am getting connection refused error.

```
@RunWith(OrderitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestOrderService extends TestCaseSrs {

    @Test
    public void testFindUsingGroovyClosure() throws IOException
    {
        RestAssured.baseURI = "http://localhost";                   
        String responseString = "Some Json";            
        String json = get("/test/Order/").asString();
        JsonPath jp = new JsonPath(json);
        String ssn = jp.get("customer.personId");
        assertEquals("123456", ssn);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Connect to localhost:8080 timed out. Connection will be retried using another IP address
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I would say that you don't have anything listening on localhost:8080

What happens if you point your browser there?

If you're running on a *nix system, then try running

`netstat -an | grep 8080`

does anything print? If not, you don't have anything listening on 8080.

It's always worth having a read of the javadoc

> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ConnectException.html
>
> Signals that an error occurred while attempting to connect a socket to
>   a remote address and port. Typically, the connection was refused
>   remotely (**e.g., no process is listening on the remote address/port)**.

Hope this helps

Will

Answer (score -1):

you can also check this link on Stack Overflow which sheds more light on the "Connection Refused Error "
[java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876266/java-net-connectexception-connection-refused)