# Eclipse Outbound connection blocked : The same url works from web browser

Tags: eclipse, connection-refused

I am using the HttpURLConnection class to connect to external web service from eclipse, then I am getting a error message "Connection Refused"

```
public class TestConnection {


    static {
        //for localhost testing only
        javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(
            new javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier(){

                    public boolean verify(String hostname,
                                      javax.net.ssl.SSLSession sslSession) {
                        if (hostname.equals("localhost")) {
                            return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {




    HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
    try {
        //https get method with required parameters
    //  XMLHttpRequest s1 = new XMLHttpRequest ();
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL("https://google.com").openConnection()));
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "");
        int HTTPS_RESPONSE_CODE = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        String HTTPS_RESULT=response.toString(); 
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

}

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at TestConnection.main(TestConnection.java:19)
```

But If i try to connect to the same site from a browser I am able to get a response from the service. Can you please let me know if there is a work around?

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876266/java-net-connectexception-connection-refused)

Comment: What URL are you trying to access?  Please post it in your OP.

Comment: This code runs completely fine on my local setup.  I am using IntelliJ, though this should not matter.  Are you sure you are running this exact code?

Comment: Yes I have posted exactly the same code, I am behind a firewall? Could this be a issue?

Comment: If you were behind a Firewall, I would expect the call from the browser to also fail.

Comment: Try using `HttpsURLConnection` instead of `HttpURLConnection`, and let me know what happens.

Comment: Tried Https Tim, Same error. I am just breaking my head now. I am able to access all the sites via a browser but not via the httpurlconnection

Comment: I get the definite feeling that Eclipse is stale and needs to be refreshed.  Again, this code runs fine from my local IDE.

Comment: We think it's a proxy issue. I will test tomorrow again and keep you posted. Thanks Tim.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `HttpURLConnection` class will not allow `localhost` as the hostname.  You need to define a custom hostname verifier which will allow `localhost`.  You can place this code into a `static` block at the top of the class where you intend to use `HttpURLConnection`:

```
public final class YourClassName {
    static {
        //for localhost testing only
        javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(
            new javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier(){

                    public boolean verify(String hostname,
                                      javax.net.ssl.SSLSession sslSession) {
                        if (hostname.equals("localhost")) {
                            return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
    }

    // use HttpURLConnection here ...
}
```

Comment: Still I am having the same issue.

Comment: Try refreshing your workspace.  This should resolve your problem.

Comment: I tried refreshing the workspace, I have added the the complete code in the question, Can you please have a look at it?

Comment: Hello Tom, added proxy settings to httpurlconnection and it worked finally

Comment: Please post an amswer to your question.  I have never seen this proxy problem before.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the working code,

PROXY_SERVER set to a valid proxy server and port for http I am using is 8080

proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(PROXY_SERVER, PROXY_PORT));

And when you establish the connection pass the proxy as an argument.

urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL(URI).openConnection(proxy)));