# java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL

Tags: java

Using java code am trying to send  HTTP POST request.
But am getting

```
 java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL
```

code

```
    try {

       String webPage = "https://testweb/test.apk?overwrite=true --data-binary @app0720.apk";
       String name = "testname";
       String password = "cpaad4%675c";

       String authString = name + ":" + password;
       System.out.println("Auth string: " + authString);            

       Base64 b = new Base64();
        String authStringEnc = b.encodeAsString(new String(authString).getBytes());

       System.out.println("Base64 encoded auth string: " + authStringEnc);

       URL url = new URL(webPage);
       URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();                         
       urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
       urlConnection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.130 Safari/537.36");
       urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Accept", "application/octet-stream");
       urlConnection.connect();

       InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
       InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
       int numCharsRead;
       char[] charArray = new char[1024];
       StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
       while ((numCharsRead = isr.read(charArray)) > 0) {
        sb.append(charArray, 0, numCharsRead);
       }
       String result = sb.toString();

       System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
       System.out.println("Response from the server: " + result);

      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

}

but when i tried in rest console it is getting properly.

Request header from REST Console

```
Accept: application/octet-stream
Authorization: Basic XXXXGHuIOIUO6hndhfhrjt
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/xml
Origin: chrome-extension: //rest-console-id
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.130 Safari/537.36
```

Response body

```
Request Url: https://testweb/test.apk?overwrite=true --data-binary @app0720.apk
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200
Params: {}
```

whats wrong with my java code.

Comment: Android? Incorrect permissions in manifest file?

Comment: Please read this post carefully: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31779791/eclipse-outbound-connection-blocked-the-same-url-works-from-web-browser/31779844#31779844

Comment: it is not for andoid...

Comment: @Psl you are sending a GET request from the given Java code. Cast `urlConnection` to `HTTPUrlConnection` and do a `urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST")`. Can't you get the log from the server to see what request he is actually receiving from this code?

Comment: Am using POST request ang getting response ode 400

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a POST call, I believe adding below statement should solve the problem.

```
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

Comment: yes i added this part also..am getting respose code 400

Comment: Response code 400 means that request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. Cross-check the data which you are posting using this `POST` call.

Comment: But when i tried thorugh rest console am getting response code 200