# Android socket Connection Refused (devices in same network)

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am trying to connect two android devices through **Socket programming**.Both the devices are in the same network so one will be acting as server and the other will be acting as client.

This is my server code:

```
 public class WhiteServer extends AsyncTask<Integer,String,String> {
private View root;

    public WhiteServer(View view){
        root = view;


    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {

        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(params[0]);
            publishProgress("Sever is active on portNumber "+params[0]);
            Socket s = serverSocket.accept();
            publishProgress("Connected client is"+s.getRemoteSocketAddress());

        } catch (IOException e) {
           publishProgress(e.toString());
        }


        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        Toast.makeText(root.getContext(),"Done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        TextView status = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.status);
        status.setText(values[0]);

    }
}
```

This is my client code:

```
public class Light extends AsyncTask<Integer,String,String> {
        private String ipAddress;
      private View view;
        public Light(String ip,View v){
            ipAddress = ip;
            view = v;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {

               try{

                   Socket client = new Socket(ipAddress,params[0]);
                   publishProgress("Connected to server on port "+client.getLocalPort());


               }catch (Exception e){
                   publishProgress(e.toString());
               }


            return "";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),values[0],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

I registered the server in port **1028** and it is listening on port **1028**.
As both devices are connected same wifi **HostName** is same for both of them.
When in server hostname and port(1028) is entered and clicked connect it says:

**java.netConnectException : Connection refused**

and also they are two different apps. Can I know how I solve this???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876266/java-net-connectexception-connection-refused)

Comment: show usage code of both async tasks

Comment: They will used on a button click

Comment: `HostName is same for both of them.`  ???? Nonsense. You should determine the ip adresses instead. The client should use the ip address of the server. `When in server hostname and port(1028) is entered and clicked connect it says:

java.netConnectException : Connection refused`. One would not enter both in a server but in a client. So you see this message in your client.

Comment: `They will used on a button click `. Please give normal answers if peaple who try to help you ask for info. Show the used code.