# Could not Connect User to Service in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio-2.2

I am using Android Studio 2.3. When I am attaching my Moto G4 to debug an application, it ends up with the following error in Android Monitor.

> 6333-7189/? I/XMPPConnection: Preparing to connect user 1576857969013772288 to service:  on host:  and port: 0
>
> 03-25 11:06:18.221 6333-7189/? E/XMPPConnectionManager: Failed to connect user '1576857969013772288' to host ' on port 0: XMPPError connecting to :0.: remote-server-error(502) XMPPError connecting to :0.
>
> -- caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

After this error, no further logs are captured even in verbose mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Check below Links:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6876306/3992798

- I am having a similar problem.
- I have an application running on Websphere 7 Dev environment 
  http://appl.company.com/appl/home.action 
  And also on my localhost system 
  http://localhost/appl/home.action
- I am trying to access a URL like below 
  http://appl.company.com/SiteContent/a.html from the above application
- It works perfectly fine on my local system.

**But on the development environment, on this particular line :-**

```
String stream = (new java.net.URL(url)).openStream();
```

- I am getting a **"java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused" exception**
- On googling i figured, such problems are either due to one of the following
- The port is wrong (cannot be this option, as same url running perfectly from local system)
- Firewall is stopping it.

Comment: As you can see, the user is not being able to connect to port 0. and following is the netstat report, which doesn't show port 0 as used:
[link] (https://anotepad.com/notes/jragig)

Answer (score 0):

The Android SDK, do you config the path?
try to it what open a cmd window,input 'adb devices',see result waht display a device of you Moto

Comment: path is not the problem. Also adb devices lists my moto and emulator.

_* daemon started successfully *_
_ZY223PG3ZL      device_
_emulator-5554   device_