# java.net.ConnectException when trying to connect in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, netbeans

I try to connect with my DB (MySQL) from a servlet but I get `Connection refused error`. I read similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876266/java-net-connectexception-connection-refused). However:

> You have not started your server.

In my local server (`Ubuntu server 16.04`), with IP `192.168.0.4` is installed `MySQL server`. `MySQL Server` is running as the command `service mysql status` give this output:

```
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Tue 2017-03-21 11:50:56 EET; 1 weeks 1 days ago
Main PID: 1209 (mysqld)
```

> You are trying to connect to the wrong IP/port.

MySQL is listening to port 3306, as the command `netstat -an | grep 3306.`
gives the following output

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

> A firewall is blocking your connection before it reaches your server.

The server's firewall is disabled, as `ufw status`

```
Status: inactive
```

I disabled my PC's firewall too but it didn't solve the connection error.

> Your server has too many pending connections waiting to be accepted.

My server is fresh installed and there is no way to have any pending connections.

> Your server is not listening for connections.

I run the commnand `nmap -sT -O localhost` and I got:

```
Not shown: 993 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
21/tcp   open  ftp
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
80/tcp   open  http
110/tcp  open  pop3
143/tcp  open  imap
3306/tcp open  mysql
```

**NETBEANS**

Me and Server we are in the same network. My Java class which handles the communication with the DB contains:

```
private final String WEBAPP_DB = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.4:3306/myDataBase";
private final String JDBC_DRIVER="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private final String USERNAME = "myUserName";
private final String PASSWORD = "myPassWord";

Connection c = null;
PreparedStatement stm = null;

sq = "SELECT * FROM Machines";
try {
    Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
    c = DriverManager.getConnection(WEBAPP_DB, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    stm = c.prepareStatement(sq);
    ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery();

    while(rs.next()){
        System.out.println("Machine = " + rs.getInt("id"));
    }

} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (stm != null) {
        stm.close();
    }
    if (c != null) {
        c.close();
    }
}
```

and some of the errors I get is

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
...
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
...
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Any hint what may be the problem?

Comment: Your database Server is listening on localhost, you use the external ip address. Change `jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.4:3306/myDataBase` to `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDataBase`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to connect yo your MySql server remotely, the problem is in the MySql server network configuration, it's listening on `localhost` (`127.0.0.1`):

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

It should be:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Or at least, instead of `0.0.0.0`, your server ip address (`192.168.0.4`).

I suggest to read this [How to Bind to Static IP address in MySQL](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33018/how-to-bind-to-static-ip-address-in-mysql)

On the other hand, if you're connecting locally (your code is executed on MySql server, which is the same machine where NetBeans runs) you should change your connection string into `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDataBase`

---

P.S. So at resuming your questionnaire :)

> You are trying to connect to the wrong IP.

Comment: Thanks for all the info! I am not connecting locally so I have to find how I can change where MySQL is listening..

Comment: Just edit `my.cfg` file and edit `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` - read [How to Bind to Static IP address in MySQL](http://askubuntu.com/questions/33018/how-to-bind-to-static-ip-address-in-mysql)

Comment: Thanks! In `Ubuntu 16.04` the file is located in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf `

Comment: @yaylitzis great ;)