# Attempting to deploy Spring Boot app Using Postgres, Tomcat, Hibernate, and getting connection refused

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, tomcat, heroku

I am attempting to deploy my webapp to heroku. Since Heroku does not allow the use of a Hibernate DB, I have setup a postgres addon and attempted to configure my app to use it.

However, when I deploy my app, it builds successfully, but when I try to open the app I get an application error. It appears that the tomcat server is unable to connect to the postgres database, and for some reason it looks like its trying to connect to localhost. The `Heroku logs` are at the bottom of this post.

**`DataConfig.java`**

```
@Configuration
public class DataConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "newsitem.db")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("newsitem.db.driver"));
        ds.setUrl(env.getProperty("newsitem.db.url"));
        ds.setUsername(env.getProperty("newsitem.db.username"));
        ds.setPassword(env.getProperty("newsitem.db.password"));
        return ds;
    }
```

**`app.properties`**

```
newsitem.db.url=${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}
newsitem.db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
newsitem.db.username=${JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME}
newsitem.db.password=${JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD}
```

This appears to be the primary cause of failure:

`Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Connection is broken: "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused): localhost" [90067-191]`

**Heroku logs:**

```
    2017-05-03T04:32:52.564241+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564242+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564245+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564246+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564246+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564247+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564248+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564249+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564250+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564250+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564251+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564252+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564253+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564253+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564254+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.3.RELEASE]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564255+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.doronzehavi.newsitemweb.Application.main(Application.java:16) [classes!/:na]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564256+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121-cedar14]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564256+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121-cedar14]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564257+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121-cedar14]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564258+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121-cedar14]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564259+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [newsitemweb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564279+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [newsitemweb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564280+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [newsitemweb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564280+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [newsitemweb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564282+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.doronzehavi.newsitemweb.dao.NewsSourceDaoImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564282+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:154) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564283+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564284+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1108) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564285+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 25 common frames omitted
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564286+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build entity manager factory
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564286+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:66) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564287+00:00 app[web.1]:    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55) ~[hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar!/:1.0.0.Final]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564288+00:00 app[web.1]:    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39) ~[hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar!/:1.0.0.Final]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564288+00:00 app[web.1]:    at com.doronzehavi.newsitemweb.dao.NewsSourceDaoImpl.<init>(NewsSourceDaoImpl.java:23) ~[classes!/:na]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564289+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121-cedar14]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564290+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121-cedar14]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564290+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_121-cedar14]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564291+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_121-cedar14]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564298+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.5.RELEASE]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564299+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 27 common frames omitted
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564300+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564300+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564301+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:228) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564302+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564302+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564303+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564304+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564304+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564306+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564307+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564311+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564312+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564312+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564313+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 35 common frames omitted
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564313+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564314+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator$1$1.convert(BasicConnectionCreator.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564315+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.convertSqlException(BasicConnectionCreator.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564315+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:41) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564316+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564317+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.addConnections(PooledConnections.java:106) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564317+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564318+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections.<init>(PooledConnections.java:19) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564319+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections$Builder.build(PooledConnections.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564319+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:110) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564320+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564321+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564322+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564323+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564324+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564325+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564323+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564325+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564326+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:254) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564327+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 46 common frames omitted
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564327+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Connection is broken: "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused): localhost" [90067-191]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564334+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345) ~[h2-1.4.191.jar!/:na]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564335+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168) ~[h2-1.4.191.jar!/:na]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564340+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:329) ~[h2-1.4.191.jar!/:na]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564340+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:107) ~[h2-1.4.191.jar!/:na]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564341+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:91) ~[h2-1.4.191.jar!/:na]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564339+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectServer(SessionRemote.java:452) ~[h2-1.4.191.jar!/:na]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564341+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:72) ~[h2-1.4.191.jar!/:na]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564343+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:38) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564344+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 61 common frames omitted
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564344+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564345+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121-cedar14]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564346+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_121-cedar14]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564347+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_121-cedar14]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564347+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_121-cedar14]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564348+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_121-cedar14]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564349+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.h2.util.NetUtils.createSocket(NetUtils.java:122) ~[h2-1.4.191.jar!/:na]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564349+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.h2.util.NetUtils.createSocket(NetUtils.java:102) ~[h2-1.4.191.jar!/:na]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564346+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_121-cedar14]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564350+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.initTransfer(SessionRemote.java:114) ~[h2-1.4.191.jar!/:na]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564350+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectServer(SessionRemote.java:448) ~[h2-1.4.191.jar!/:na]
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564351+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 66 common frames omitted
2017-05-03T04:32:52.564351+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-05-03T04:32:52.683659+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-05-03T04:32:52.698197+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-05-03T04:33:21.797903+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=intense-hamlet-29713.herokuapp.com request_id=9d7158ad-6410-49bd-83d0-c072f54fdc81 fwd="198.27.128.5" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-05-03T04:33:22.569682+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=intense-hamlet-29713.herokuapp.com request_id=2894c36e-db93-472e-9faf-553db67c84db fwd="198.27.128.5" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876266/java-net-connectexception-connection-refused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the H2 db driver. Look at this line in the stacktrace :

```
org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:72) ~[h2-1.4.191.jar!/:na]
```

Use the right jdbc driver.