# JedisConnectionException while using jedis in multi threaded environment

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I am facing an issue in which we are getting JedisConnectionException because of timed out. Ours is a multi threaded environment and we are using redis extensively. We are creating the redis pool with the below config,

```
  JedisPoolConfig config = new JedisPoolConfig();
    config.setTestOnBorrow(true); config.setMaxIdle(1000);
     config.setMaxTotal(1000); config.setBlockWhenExhausted(true);
     config.setMaxWaitMillis(180000); pool = new JedisPool(config,
     getHost(), getPort());
```

We are releasing the resource back to pool after every use.
The exception is as follows

> redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get
>   a resource from the pool  at
>   redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:42)
>   Caused by:
>   redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused     at
>   redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:142)   at
>   redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:75)    at
>   redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.connect(BinaryJedis.java:1724)    at
>   redis.clients.jedis.JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisFactory.java:65)     at
>   org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:868)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:435)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363)
>     at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:40)    ... 4 more
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused  at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)

Can some one please suggest?

Comment: Sorry to mention that we are using elastic cache .

Comment: Looks either like a firewall issue or the cache is down, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876266/java-net-connectexception-connection-refused.

Comment: Check also the trivial - make sure the host and port are correct.