# I can't find my port number at my IP address

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, serversocket

I am trying to create a chat with **Socket**. And to do this, I need to use a **class in JAVA** called *Socket*. It has, in my case, two **parameters**: `Socket(InetAddress address, int port)`.
I know what is my IP, by the command in CMD: `ipconfig`

But I don't know what to *put in my port number*, because I  **don't**  know where I can find it.
Is there any command, application or others things to get **port number**?
I use `textpad 8` to create *JAVA programs*.

There is two programs, the **transmitter** and the **receiver**.
**Transmitter code**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Program
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {

            ServerSocket request = new ServerSocket(12345);
            Socket connection = request.accept();
            PrintWriter transmitter = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

                String line = null;

                do
                {

                    line = keyboard.readLine();
                    transmitter.println(line);
                    transmitter.flush();

                }
                while (line==null || !line.toUpperCase().equals("END"));

                    transmitter.close();
                    connection.close();
                    request.close();

        }

        catch(Exception error)
        {
            System.out.println("Communication error");
        }

    }
}
```

**Receiver code**

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Programa
{

public static void main(String[] args) {

            try
            {
            Socket connection = new Socket("123.456.78.9",12345);
            BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            BufferedReader receptor = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conexao.getInputStream()));

                String line = null;
                do
                {

                        line=receptor.readLine();
                        System.out.println(line);

                }
                while(line==null || !line.toUpperCase().equals("END"));
                receptor.close();
                connection.close();
            }

            catch(Exception error)
            {
                System.out.println("Communication error");
                System.out.println("Error: " + error);
            }
        }
 }
```

Comment: A PC doesn't have a port number, an application listens on a port number.  You get to choose one.

Comment: And what I need to do to get this number of ports?

Comment: @Grandtour the port number is of your choice. Anyway you should not use a [standard port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) or a port that another process is [already using](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat). Your client must know the address and **the port**.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that, thank you. But I already have an error: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Comment: Is there any service listening to the IP/port you are trying to connect?

Comment: No, I already checked.

Comment: so it will definitely throw an exception.

Comment: Yes, there is a try and a catch and the error is in the beginning of the try.

Comment: @Grandtour , so post your code.

Comment: Ok, just wait a minute...

Comment: I am fighting, against this error: java.net.ConnectException: Connection

Comment: @Grandtour - Post the complete stack trace of the exception by editing this question!

Comment: @Grandtour disable all firewalls temporary, to check it is not an issue. Further read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876266/java-net-connectexception-connection-refused

Comment: 1. Did you run the server before running the client? 2. You should have ` while (line != null ...`.

Answer (score 1):

"port" argument in this constructor is the port on which you want to run your service. It is not related to the system. You can pass it as any port number on which you want this service to run.

Comment: Are you sure that is any port number?

Comment: You can use any port number as the argument on which you want to run your chat service. Your service will be accessible through that port number that you pass.

Comment: But when I put any port number, it shows me that error: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Comment: First start the server on that port. Then use a client to access the service on that port. The error is coming because there is no service running on the port that you are trying to access. Here is a sample server code to get you started. Use ServerSocket to start a service on a port.Link 
 to Refer: https://www.javatpoint.com/socket-programming

Comment: I don't know how to start the server on that port. '-'

Comment: Please refer to the link mentioned above and check MyServer.java.ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(portNumber);  
Socket s=ss.accept()

Answer (score 0):

The address gets you to the machine.  The machine the receives this request, and based on the added port number directs the network traffic to a running program.

If you don't know which program is supposed to receive your request, you need to find out.  Then you need to find out what port number that program is listening to.  What the phrase "listening to" really means is "what port number the operating system will interpert as traffic that needs to be sent to the program".

If you were writing both a client and a server, then a parameter of the `ServerSocket` you will create in the server, will be the port number to "accept requests" on.  For the server, this is actually a request to the operating system to have traffic tagged with this port number to be redirected as input ready to be read on the `ServerSocket`.

If you have no idea what ports are being handled by server programs, and you are logged into that server, and the server is a Linux server, you can run the command

```
lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN
```

which will list all the ports where a server like program is listening.

If you are not on that machine, you can use a tool like `nmap` but I would advise against using it on someone else's network without prior permission.  Many people use `nmap` to discover possible routes of attacking a server, so an miscommunication in your intention could result in their believing you are a malicious attacker.

Comment: Because it tells me that 'lsof' is not recognized as an internal or external command, an operational program or a batch file.

Comment: @Grandtour I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that that command is for a Linux server.  It has been so long since I've used a Microsoft operating system, I have no idea how to do it on such a machine.

Answer (score 0):

Port 8100 is a pretty safe bet.  That said, a port is a whole number less than 65536 that an application can listen and respond to on one or more IP addresses.  An application listening on a specific TCP port should be the *only* application listening on that port.  Some port assignments are "well known" and you can avoid potential conflicts by looking them up even if you don't happen to be running one of those applications at the time.  (See, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers).

If you might want to share your Java app with a friend who uses Linux some time in the future, you should avoid using ports under 1024 or they'll need to configure special permissions.

So, the conflict-avoidance game is played by first avoiding commonly-used ports and ports and low-numbered ports, then pick from the remaining ones available and verify to see that your system isn't already using it.  You can do so on Windows with the netstat command like so:

```
netstat -a -b | findstr 8100
```

If you see output with the word "LISTENING", then pick another, perhaps 8101, 8102, etc.  If no results show up after, say, 10 seconds, then you've picked a winner.  You can also leave off the `| findstr xxxx` portion and look at the results.  It's sorted by port number, so you can just pick a port somewhere between two other acceptable TCP port numbers.