# Ignite node not getting started in client mode

Tags: java, performance, ignite

I have one server node running and trying to run one client node in my application by providing xml configuration but it is getting stuck due to exception on joining server node but when I check in visorcmd server node is active and I can see in the topology.
In the client logs I observed that,client keep on printing logs until tomcat in which application is running times out. 
Below is the logs snapshot :

```
[11:31:34,063][SEVERE][grid-nio-worker-client-listener-0-#30][ClientListenerProcessor]Failed to pro
cess selector key [ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [worker=ByteBufferNioClientWorker [readBuf=java.ni

[11:31:34,063][SEVERE][grid-nio-worker-client-listener-0-#30][ClientListenerProcessor] Failed to pro
cess selector key [ses=GridSelectorNioSessionImpl [worker=ByteBufferNioClientWorker [readBuf=java.ni
o.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=8192 cap=8192], super=AbstractNioClientWorker [idx=0, bytesRcvd=0, bytesS
ent=0, bytesRcvd0=0, bytesSent0=0, select=true, super=GridWorker [name=grid-nio-worker-client-listen
er-0, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, hashCode=1991420534, interrupted=false, runner=grid-n
io-worker-client-listener-0-#30]]], writeBuf=null, readBuf=null, inRecovery=null, outRecovery=null,
super=GridNioSessionImpl [locAddr=/192.168.0.117:10800, rmtAddr=/192.168.0.117:49596, createTime=151
9192525035, closeTime=0, bytesSent=1189, bytesRcvd=4596, bytesSent0=0, bytesRcvd0=0, sndSchedTime=15
19192526915, lastSndTime=1519192526915, lastRcvTime=1519192526825, readsPaused=false, filterChain=Fi
lterChain[filters=[GridNioAsyncNotifyFilter, GridNioCodecFilter [parser=ClientListenerBufferedParser
, directMode=false]], accepted=true]]]
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$ByteBufferNioClientWorker.processRead(G
ridNioServer.java:1068)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.processSelected
KeysOptimized(GridNioServer.java:2272)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.bodyInternal(Gr
idNioServer.java:2048)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.body(GridNioSer
ver.java:1717)
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

But if the same application is started in server mode no error occurs and application starts as expected.

Comment: share logs by -DIGNITE_QUIET=false and set more heap size(512mb+)

Comment: Most probably, it fails to find the server node. You can check that by starting another server node with the same configuration and checking the number of nodes in topology.
Try switching to TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder and removing the multicastGroup parameter.

Comment: @Guarav Thanks for response. My application starts the client node via xml configuration. Can you please guide me how to set -DIGNITE_QUIET=false in igniteconfiguration?

Comment: @Denis Thanks for the response. It was working with the multicast configuration, but since 2 days it stopped working. And When it could not find a server node it gives connection Error.

Comment: So, does it find another node if you start a server instead?

Comment: Yes it does find any other server node in the same multicast group but currently client node not getting started and there is no exception at all

Comment: @Gaurav I have shared the client logs by setting heap size and -DIGNITE_QUIET=false. but getting connection exception but server node is already active.

Comment: @PriyankaS : refer this answer for this exception: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876266/java-net-connectexception-connection-refused

Comment: @PriyankaS What is your environment (VMs, physical machines, containers, what is the network between them, etc)? Can you reproduce the issue in another environment?

Comment: @StanislavLukyanov : Thanks for your response. server node is running on a physical machine (through ignite.bat) and client application also runs on the same machine.Now I am not getting any connection issue but getting error as "Failed to pro
cess selector" on server node while starting client. I have added the recent logs.

Comment: @PriyankaS If you have multiple questions/problems, please separate them. If your initial issue was resolved, please write an answer yourself describing the solution - by doing that you will help community and other people who may be struggling with the same issues.