# WebGoat - web service SQL injection testing with Webscarab fails

Tags: web-services, websecurity, webscarab

Could someone please tell me why do I see the following error message:

[image: webscarab error]

when trying to complete WebGoat web service SQL injection by using Webscarab? I'm on Win. Thank you.

Comment: "connection refused" usually indicates the request didn't reach any running service. Either the URL you're using is incorrect, or there is no service running at the URL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876266/java-net-connectexception-connection-refused)

Comment: I removed the [tag:sql-injection] tag, because the error has nothing to do with SQL injection. It's a network connection error.

Comment: thanks Bill. unfortunately none of your suggestions solved my problem but i appreciate your help. will keep searching.

Comment: WebScarab hasnt been maintained for many years - you'd be much better off using OWASP ZAP :)

Comment: thanks for the hint Simon, i might try it :)