# ASyncTask ConnectException : Connection refused

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm testing my Application that is running on android using android studio. 
but I encountered problem "Java.net.ConnectException:Connection refused" by using HttpURLConnection.getConnection().

I already tried these:

- Check the server is running?
- access url from browser

This is my AsyncTask class:

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        protected  void onPostExecute(String... params){
            resValue = params[0];
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            URL url;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            System.out.println(params[0]);
            try {
                url = new URL(params[0]);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid url");
            }

            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            try {
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoOutput(false);
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setUseCaches(false);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");

                // handle the response
                int status = conn.getResponseCode();
                if (status != 200) {
                    throw new IOException("Post failed with error code " + status);
                } else {
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                    String inputLine;
                    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(inputLine);
                    }
                    in.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.disconnect();
                }

                String responseJSON = response.toString();
                System.out.print("This is doInBackground "+responseJSON);
                return responseJSON;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: I would suggest using a proper http client like Volley or Retrofit, so that you don't need an AsyncTask but it also isn't clear what url you're using

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876266/java-net-connectexception-connection-refused)

Comment: the example is work for me but My app is not.. why??

Comment: maybe.... because of my server is localhost?...... other domain is just work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post the url you are using, it might be the problem. You should be using 10.0.2.2 ip instead of 127.0.0.1, because it is a default loopback interface ip.

Comment: even I using localhost web server?

Comment: yes, check this out: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html