# Gradle Build Error on the First Launch of Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

Gradle build error on the first launch of my android studio.

[image]

Comment: is your internet connection working?

Comment: Also please make sure you didn't do some changes in your /etc/hosts file sometimes it can mess up. Make sure that your localhost is pointing to 127.0.0.1 and not to dynamically changing ip address.

Answer (score 3):

Check your firewall or your network configuration. When I first time launch android studio I facing the same issues, then I realized that the problem is on my firewall configuration. Gradle needs an internet connection to download the dependencies that you specify.

[java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876266/java-net-connectexception-connection-refused)

Answer (score 0):

Kindly clean your project once and again apply a Gradle build then try to resolve the Error
which defined in your screenshot.

Another option is to check your dependencies in the Project structure.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the Firewall configuration that is causing this error , to make sure you can connect VPN to run project as it will run normally.So change your Firewall configuration.