# react native java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Tags: react-native

I just created a react native project, It runs fine until I added the package `"react-native-fs": "2.20.0"` to dependencies. `"react-native-fs": "2.20.0"` is not the only package that has the issue, some others packages also cause this issue but some don't (ex: `"microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk": "1.31.0"`)

Here is the stack trace

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.privilegedOpenServer(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.legacy.remote.internal.DownloadCache.openUrl(DownloadCache.java:245)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.legacy.remote.internal.DownloadCache.downloadAndCache(DownloadCache.java:622)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.legacy.remote.internal.DownloadCache.openCachedUrl(DownloadCache.java:453)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.legacy.LegacyDownloader.downloadAndStream(LegacyDownloader.java:82)
        at com.android.repository.impl.downloader.LocalFileAwareDownloader.downloadAndStream(LocalFileAwareDownloader.java:51)
        at com.android.repository.impl.manager.RemoteRepoLoaderImpl.lambda$fetchPackages$0(RemoteRepoLoaderImpl.java:138)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my package.json file

```
    {
  "name": "com.example.app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest --coverage",
    "pod-install": "RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED=1 bundle exec pod install"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk": "1.31.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.4",
    "react-native-fs": "2.20.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "^0.72.2",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.72.11",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.76.8",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876266/java-net-connectexception-connection-refused)

Comment: I'm afraid not, that one they do touch the network in java code, the error is similar but in my case I just add a library to package.json and the error happened, if I don't add that library but add a different one (ex: `microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk`) it's still work fine.

Comment: The error suggests otherwise, that it does try to connect to something, at that thing is refusing the connection.

Comment: this error happens on my mac, just tried on windows and it worked, not sure what's wrong with my mac