# Tomcat Server not starting with in X seconds

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, eclipse-plugin

I have tried the following

[Delete & add server again](http://sansatechnology.wordpress.com/2011/09/26/how-to-fix-eclipse-tomcat-not-starting-in-45-seconds/)

[Delete snap file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15498724/tomcat-server-not-starting-with-in-45-seconds)

[increased the timeout to 180](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468520/server-tomcat-v6-0-server-at-localhost-was-unable-to-start-within-45-seconds)

```
Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost was unable to start within 180 seconds. If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor.
```

I'm using `eclipse-jee-juno-SR2-win32-x86_64` under `Win8`

```
    SEVERE: A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/cloud_demo_3]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/cloud_demo_3]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        ... 7 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [CompareCriterionSlider] and [ahp.CompareCriterionSlider] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/compare_criterion_slider] which is not permitted
        at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:335)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationWebServlet(ContextConfig.java:2457)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2139)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2100)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2093)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1300)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:369)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5269)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 7 more

    May 23, 2013 3:00:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
    SEVERE: A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:684)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 7 more

    May 23, 2013 3:00:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    SEVERE: Catalina.start: 
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:684)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 7 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 9 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 11 more

    May 23, 2013 3:00:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFO: Server startup in 579 ms
```

Removed the following code in `web.xml`:

```
        <servlet>
          <servlet-name>CompareCriterionSlider</servlet-name>
          <servlet-class>ahp.CompareCriterionSlider</servlet-class>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>CompareCriterionSlider</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>/compare_criterion_slider</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is listed in the log:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [CompareCriterionSlider] and [ahp.CompareCriterionSlider] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/compare_criterion_slider] which is not permitted
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:335)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationWebServlet(ContextConfig.java:2457)
```

Please fix your servlet configuration in the web.xml